# Doubling hbox returned height

Tags: height

I can get the height of the hbox but I am stuck trying to double its height.  Here my latex statements:

```
\newlength{\txtlineheight}
\settoheight{\txtlineheight}{\hbox{Hello World!}}
\settoheight{\txtlineheight}{\txtlineheight*2}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `\setlength`?

```
\newlength{\txtlineheight}
\settoheight{\txtlineheight}{Hello World!}
\setlength{\txtlineheight}{2\txtlineheight}
```

Also, `\settoheight` already puts its argument into a box, thus the `\hbox` is superfluous.

If calculations are needed, package `calc` can be loaded. But this is not necessary for doubling, because `2` can be used as factor for the length.

Another way for calculations is available with e-TeX's `\dimexpr`.